# HTML5 Canvas Line Graph, where user inputs data

Tags: html, loops, canvas, graph, line

I'm having a bit of problem with my HTML5 Canvas Graph. This might be a little difficult to explain so please bear with me.

I need to create a graph on HTML5 Canvas so that the position of each point on the chart is based on the value of a drop down menu underneath it. Whenever the value is changed, the chart must be redrawn so that there is no overlap. See here on how it will look: http://cl.ly/image/070C2g1I0f2u
Underneath each point, there will be a drop down menu with several values.

This code is for the array of 7 drop down menus:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
var select = document.getElementById("graph"); 
var el = document.createElement("select");
el.setAttribute('id', 'no' +i);
select.appendChild(el);

        var percents = new Array(21)
        for(var z = 0; z < percents.length; z++){
        var days = document.getElementById('no' + i);
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = z*5;
        days.add(option);
        } 
}

<div id = "graph">
<table id = "no_table">
</table>
</div>
```

What I need now is to link each of these drop down boxes to its' corresponding point on the graph. I can draw 7 circles on the canvas.. but how can I make it so that I can:

- draw these circles in a **for loop**
- while linking each circle to each drop down box and its values
- and also taking into account the width and height of the canvas (width =600 height =400)
- While the graph is redrawn each time a value is changed?
- each of these circles must be connected with a line

I would really appreciate any help on this. Please let me know if I am confusing you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code for you to start with:

- create a `days` object with each day name and it's percentage value.
- programmatically create a select element for each day of the week with 3 percentage options each.
- listen for change events on select elements
- redraw the html canvas graph when the data changes.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/k4Zr9/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas and context variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // graph styling variables
    var x1=50;
    var yAxis=200;
    var margin=30;

    // an object with the percentage value for each day
    var days={
        Sunday:0,
        Monday:0,
        Tuesday:0,
        Wednesday:0,
        Thursday:0,
        Friday:0,
        Saturday:0
    }

    // each day will have 3 percentage options
    var options=[
        {val:0,text:"0%"},
        {val:50,text:"50%"},
        {val:100,text:"100%"},
    ];

    // build the html select elements for each day of the week
    for(var dayName in days){

        var select = $('<select>').attr("id",dayName).addClass("myData").appendTo('body');
        $(options).each(function() {
         select.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
        });

    };

    // listen for change events on the comboboxes
    // redraw the graph accordingly
    $(".myData").change(function(e){
        days[this.id]=$(this).val();
        draw();
    });

    // draw the beginning graph
    draw();


    function draw(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        var i=0;
        for(var day in days){

            var value=days[day];

            if(day=="Sunday"){
                ctx.moveTo(x1+margin*(i++),yAxis-days[day]);
            }else{
                ctx.lineTo(x1+margin*(i++),yAxis-days[day]);          
            }

        }
        ctx.stroke();

        var i=0;
        for(var day in days){

            var value=days[day];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc( x1+margin*(i++), yAxis-value,8,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

        }

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="selects"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```